# Please Explain Dictionary Form + って (いるって)

Tags: particles, colloquial-language

I came across the sentence, ともだちがいるってすてきだなあ.  If someone could explain the いるって part, dictionary form+って, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「ともだちがいる**って**すてきだなあ。」

In this context,

> 「～～って」＝「～～というのは」

In informal speech, 「～～って」 is used to ***present a word/phrase/sentence as a topic***.  Here, 「ともだちがいる」("that one has friends") is being presented as a topic (and the speaker is saying that 'it is nice').

Attention:  This is ***not*** the quotative 「って」.

Comment: So it is interchangeable with は and considered as informal? As in ともだち が いる は すてきだなあ。。。why we need が いる? What additional meaning it hold?

Comment: @Alice28 No, it's not. は following terminal forms of verbs has another function (though the standard orthography is わ) and in this case the sentence doesn't make sense. I think this って is still quotative and the nature of a topic marker mostly comes from the null marker after it. ともだちがいる means "there are friends / you have friends".

Comment: True, my Japanese teacher said that って following a dictionary form can be used to present a word/phrase/sentence as a topic; however, it is not entirely equivalent to the regular topic particle は。 Now, って as a topic indicator is only used when the topic phrase has been mentioned by your opponent speaker, and the use of って is trying to remind the opponent speaker that I'm addressing something that you just said earlier.